# Replacement for Android Mapview to use a WMS service

Tags: android, android-webview, android-mapview, osmdroid, wms

I am looking for a replacement for the Android MapView, because I need to add a WMS service within a map view and it works very poorly using the native view.

I have tried using [Osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) API for this, but still without success. This requires modifying several java classes as XYTileSource and BitmapTileSourceBase. And I'm not sure I can work because I have not found information about it.

for example: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/osmdroid/IUcc4Q0DmOE

There are applications in the Android Market that can make this work perfectly as OruxMaps but not have an API for development. : (

Anyone have any idea of ​​how to use a WMS service in another map view, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the API from mapforges:
http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

Answer (score 0):

You can try Nutiteq, their API is quite impressive and has lots of features:

http://www.nutiteq.com/content/different-map-sources

Comment: There is new version of that now, with 3D capabilities:  http://nutiteq.github.com/hellomap3d/. WMS sample: https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/WMS-map-layer